# vim: strange behavior with search-replace

Tags: vim

Here's my code:

```
public function setFileAvatar($fileAvatar)
{
    $this->fileAvatar=$fileAvatar;
}
```

I select the whole code with "`V`" (note the upcase) then I type: "`:'<,'>s/ileAvatar/ileNameAvatar`" which is supposed to replace **ALL** "`ileAvatar`" by "`ileNameAvatar`"

But here's the result:

```
public function setFileNameAvatar($fileAvatar)
{
    $this->fileNameAvatar=$fileAvatar;
}
```

The `$fileAvatar` are not replaced! How comes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your substitution is missing the `/g` flag; only the *first occurrence* in each line is replaced.

If you make this mistake frequently, you can consider changing the default via `:set gdefault`.

Comment: Thank you for this! +1 for you! Have a nice day! **`;^D`**